# How to align an HDF layer

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, hdf

Forgive me, but I am completely new to GIS.
I am using QGIS.

I have a raster layer (HDF format) that does not align with other layers.
All layers are projected WGS84 (EPSG:4326) and still the problem persists.
I know that the HDF layer is defined by rows and columns that need to be converted to longitudes and latitudes but I don't know how to do that.
Also, the HDF file, for some reason, can't be exported as CSV file.

[image]

Comment: Are you *sure* that the projection is correct? Can you get the GDALinfo for each file please, that would explain a lot. It's in you QGIS bin directory gdalinfo.exe, use in cmd window gdalinfo <full path to file>. It looks to me that the black/white image is not georeferenced, it's sitting at 0,0 and trending southeast.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, HDF files come with georeferencing information. If QGIS does not read it automatically, you have to look that up on the download page, or ask the provider.

Don't use `Set CRS for Layer` inside QGIS to change the CRS. This will corrupt your data.

If the HDF has another CRS than your picture, use `On-The-Fly-Reprojection`, or `Save As` providing a different filename and the target CRS you desire.

---

**EDIT**
If the hdf is in degrees, with corner coordinates of the whole world, you can extract the subdata layer you want and add the corner coordinates using gdal_transform:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr -180 -90 180 90 -of "Gtiff" HDF4_SDS:UNKOWN:"LISOTD_HRFC_V2.3.2013.hdf":0 test.tif
```

You have to run gdalinfo on the file to get the correct name of the subdata layer:

```
gdalinfo LISOTD_HRFC_V2.3.2013.hdf
```

Comment: I thought it looked ungeoreferenced, that totally explains it. Does GDAL_Translate read the coordinate information? i.e. can you translate to GeoTIFF for example to avoid this difficulty with HDF files?

Comment: There are many flavours of HDF out there. GDAL has some options to cope with them. See https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/HDF and the linked pages.